# Lumen Install - TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Composer\Package\Locker::__construct()

Tags: php, composer-php, lumen

I am trying to install Lumen on Mac OS 11.5.2. Running the command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen app` returns a fatal error of:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Composer\Package\Locker::__construct() must be an instance of Composer\Installer\InstallationManager, instance of Composer\Repository\RepositoryManager given, called in /Users/macbox/.composer/vendor/foxy/foxy/Util/LockerUtil.php on line 41 and defined in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Locker.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/macbox/.composer/vendor/foxy/foxy/Util/LockerUtil.php(41): Composer\Package\Locker->__construct(Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO), Object(Composer\Json\JsonFile), Object(Composer\Repository\RepositoryManager), Object(Composer\Installer\InstallationManager), '{\n    "name": "...')
#1 /Users/macbox/.composer/vendor/foxy/foxy/Fallback/ComposerFallback.php(101): Foxy\Util\LockerUtil::getLocker(Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO), Object(Composer\Repository\RepositoryManager), Object(Composer\Installer\InstallationManager), './composer.json')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(217) : eval()' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Locker.php on line 60
```

I am running PHP version 7.4.2 and composer version 2.1.8.

Has anybody run into this issue before and found a solution? I haven't been able to find any similar issues.